# Group by calendar week crossing years

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'd like to group data by calendar week. However, I have data over many years. So not by the week number alone, but for every year separately. Here's an example.

```
ix = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2019-12-25', '2019-12-28', '2019-12-31', '2020-01-03'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [1, 1, 1, 1]}, index=ix)
```

My problem is that days of the first week are still in the previous year.

```
>>> df.groupby([ix.year, ix.month, ix.week]).count()

            count
2019 12 1       1
        52      2
2020 1  1       1
```

How could I group to yield the calendar weeks? Here it would produce two groups of two rows.

Comment: Did you try `.weekofyear`, but not sure if that is any different than `.week`?

Comment: @davidbilla In my experience it's the same thing :/

Comment: I thought so. I think when you get .week for 12/31/19 it is 1, because there is no 53rd week

Comment: @davidbilla Yep, that would be fine without the yearly aspect.

Comment: I guess you should divide the dayofyear by 7 and compute your weeks

Comment: @davidbilla I'm not sure if that would work, because the first day of the year is not necessarily a monday. But that could be used if there is no straightforward way.

Comment: Yes you're right

Comment: I think then we need to compute the week number from epoch time

Comment: Look at a calender of 2020. The first week of 2020 starts at 30.12.2019 - Calendar weeks are difficult. The first week of 2021 starts on 04.01.2021 - the first week of 2019 started on 31.12.2019.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I recognise they are difficult, hence the question. I came up with this example specifically by looking at the calendar. But thanks for the clarification anyway :D

Comment: @Patrick To make things worse the algorithm for determining the first week of the year depends on your locale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the number of weeks from epoch date (1/1/1970) might help.

```
day_delta = pd.to_datetime(df.index) - pd.to_datetime('19700101')
df['day'] = (day_delta / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')).astype(int) - 3     # considering week start as sunday
df['week'] = df['day'].apply(lambda x: int(x / 7))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
            col    day  week
2019-12-25    1  18252  2607
2019-12-28    1  18255  2607
2019-12-31    1  18258  2608
2020-01-03    1  18261  2608
```

This gives 2019-12-31 and 2020-01-03 in the same week.

I guess you need to compute the month number and year number from epoch date and group them using year, month and week number (from epoch date)

Comment: If I understood right, weeks starting from monday would `-2`, right?